# How To Fix 'No mapping exists from object type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter to a known managed provider native type.' error in ASP.Net

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call stored procedure from a controller. It's values come from ajax to controller. How can I resolve this error I'm getting?

Here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Get_OADetails_By_Customer]
    @CustCode NVARCHAR(15),
    @Status INT,
    @Sdate NVARCHAR(20),
    @Edate NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT   
        O.OANO, O.OADate, O.PONO, O.PODATE,
        SO.POLI, SO.ID, SO.MOULDCODE, SO.DESCRIPTION,
        SO.Drg, SO.Rev, M.METALNAME,
        SO.QTY, U.UNITName, SO.DELIVERYDT 
    FROM
        OADetails AS O 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        CustomerDetails AS C ON O.PCODE = C.PCODE 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        SubOADetail AS SO ON O.OANO = SO.OANO 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        MetalDetails AS M ON SO.METALCODE = M.METALCODE 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        UNITMaster AS U ON SO.UNIT = U.UNITID 
    WHERE
        C.CUSTCODE = @CustCode 
        AND O.Status = @Status 
        AND o.OADATE BETWEEN @Sdate AND @Edate
END
```

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOADetailByCustomer(string custcode, int status, string yr)
{
        var CST = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "CUSTCODE",
            Value = custcode
        };

        var ST = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "Status",
            Value = status
        };

        var yearval = Db.Years.Where(x => x.YEAR1 == yr).FirstOrDefault();

        var courseList = Db.Database.SqlQuery<OADetail>("exec sp_OADetails_Get @CustCode, @Status, @Sdate, @Edate",
            new SqlParameter("@CustCode", CST),
            new SqlParameter("@Status", ST),
            new SqlParameter("@Sdate", yearval.SDATE),
            new SqlParameter("@Edate", yearval.EDATE)).FirstOrDefault<OADetail>();
        return View();
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: As indicated in the exception message, a SqlParameter object cannot be used as a value to a (new) SqlParameter object. The code is doubling up the number of SqlParamater objects for ST/CST, with the latter wrapping the former.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as the person user2864740 said, you are doubling up the SqlParameters

Thus change to the following below are that will fix it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOADetailByCustomer(string custcode, int status, string yr)
{
        var CST = custcode;
        var ST = status;

        var yearval = Db.Years.Where(x => x.YEAR1 == yr).FirstOrDefault();

        var courseList = Db.Database.SqlQuery<OADetail>("exec sp_OADetails_Get @CustCode, @Status, @Sdate, @Edate",
            new SqlParameter("@CustCode", CST),
            new SqlParameter("@Status", ST),
            new SqlParameter("@Sdate", yearval.SDATE),
            new SqlParameter("@Edate", yearval.EDATE)).FirstOrDefault<OADetail>();
        return View();
}
```